# how to use JSON in node js typescripty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have trying to use JSON type in my node js application but i am getting data in some data of scripted type.

my response
},
data: '\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00]PMo�0\f�-�ykӬ_ ��\n' +
'(\x14�\x1AVi�K\x15�\x00�4�\x14\x01���RN\x13��z�{~���\taJ�Z����\x16\x00�\x10�>�5rç\x18�c���\x1D:�ɓ���y5[\x15�N��\V����Eq�SyD�\ff� ށ\x07�\x1C\x7F|Wiw�f�M��%����&[���↸��\t���J(�\x05ae�r��u���c�x���(;�\n' +
'\x0B��\x17����3��-a6�u/A�\x115S�aĩ��p�8N\r���\x1D\x02�ə�qj��(��aF3a�em�A���\x12k\x03�A0�a\x04#\x1F\x00��T�\x17XwmO �5C��nV��ħ�&?ɐ�/�d4Ab���Y�!y�~�\x00�\x16�:\x7F\x01\x00\x00'
}

i can't use JSON in application,even after using express.json in index.ts file

```
   require("dotenv").config();
import express, { Request, Response, Express } from "express";

import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";
import sfHelper from "./v1/helper/sfhelper";
import getconfigdata from "./v1/helper/confighelper";
import router from "./router/index";
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors')

const app: Express = express();

app.use("/api", router);

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));

app.listen(process.env.PORT, async () => {
  console.log("App Runnig in 4000");
});
```

Comment: try to use router middleware after bodyparser middleware.

Comment: I have tried it but it given same response

Comment: Can you show your whole index.ts file

Comment: i have updated the file can you please take a look

Comment: You don't need both `express.json` and `bodyparser.json`, they do the same thing. Whichever you use, it should be above the `app.use("/api", router)`. If that doesn't fix things, can you log out the content-type of the request to see if it's actually JSON?

Comment: I have logged my response type i am getting the data in the form of string

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @ZacAnger you should declare your middleware before the routes.
There is no need to use `body-parser` (which is also deprecated):

```
const app: Express = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, async () => {
  console.log('App Runnig in 4000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used **fetch** instead of **axios** it fixed my problem,i am not sure use axios is giving this response